# How to calculate the area of the visible parts of a 3D PieChart?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, surfaces, area

I have created a 3D Pie Chart whose major feat (among the others) is to be rotated:

[image]

I did it to demonstrate how the visual perception of data in a Pie Chart can be distorted depending on the position, so that with a 3D pie chart, the closer the slices are, the more important they 'seem' perceptively, since they occupy a bigger area (area of ellipse + visible area of cylinder's side), while the more distant they are the less important they look, since they occupy a smaller area (only the ellipse's area, without the cylinder's), despite all numerical weighs being equal.

A method of evaluation of how much a slice's weigh is perceived compared to its basic weigh (the percentage), is the area of the slices of the 3D Pie Chart (inner pie area + outer pie area).

In order to demonstrate my point, I need to calculate the total visual area of the slices.

What approach is best to be used ?

> EDIT 1

I was able to calculate the **total** visible area of the PieChart by using the formulas to calculate the area of a cylinder, as shown below.

[image] [image]

**Area of Pie Chart** = Area of Ellipse + Area of Cylinder's side
[image]

**AE** -> (Area of Ellipse):

[image]

**PE** -> (Perimeter of Ellipse) (It is an approximation):

[image]

**ACS** -> (Area of Cylinder's side):

ACS = PE * H (height of cylinder)

**VACS** -> Visible part of Cylinder's Area's side:
VACS = ACS / 2

Total Visible Area of Pie Chart -> **AE + VACS**

> EDIT 2

I was also able to calculate the slice closest to the viewer (the one having 29.5%):

For each slice: 
- AE * percentage
e.g. if AE is 74.28, then the light blue slice within the Ellipse (29.5%) must be:

[image]

then the light blue slice's outer side, with VACS = 25.36:

[image]

the result for the light blue slice would be -> **21.9126 + 7.4812 = 29,3938**

> but what about the other 2 (26% and 10.1%)?

Comment: Are you doing this for math fun, or for a demonstration of your point? If the latter, I would recommend writing some code to count pixels of the image based on color. If the former, do you have exact specifications of the height of the cylinder and is the viewing angle always fixed?